# gnuplot label not displayed

Tags: label, gnuplot

I have lots of files to generate a plot for and therefore wrote a little script for gnuplot.
I want to add additional information with a label underneath the graph but my label is not displayed on the generated image.
Anyone gut an idea?

load.plt:

```
# template.gnuplot
set terminal png
filename = "results-05112012-".i.".dat"
plotfile = "results-05112012-".i.".png"
print filename." ".plotfile

set grid
set title "EER"" 
set output plotfile
set label "m = 20" at 0, 3 front tc rgb "#ffffff"
plot[0.35:0.75][0:100] filename using 1:6 title "FAR" w lp, filename using 1:7 title "FRR" w lp
unset output
unset label

i=i+1

if(i <= n) reread
```

Comment: Does this script work?  The first time through the loop, `i` isn't defined.

Comment: Come to think of it, `n` isn't defined either.  Are you passing that on the commandline?

Comment: You also seem to have an additional `"` in the `set title` line.  Gnuplot's parser doesn't seem to like that when I type it in interactively

Comment: okay so the double " is a typo of myself deleting unnecessary information from title. i and n are passed from cmdline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two reasons why the label might not appear.  One is that the label is at the point (0,3) which is not within the plot region [0.35:0.75][0:100].  The other is that the label is white in color (#ffffff).

Comment: The point outside the plot region isn't a problem (unless it is far enough out of the plot region to also put it off the screen region).  But, in this case, it's probably best to specify the label position in `screen` coordinates.  `set label 'foo' at screen 0.5,.95` ... The white label color is definitely fishy though (+1 for catching that).

Comment: both your answers helped me. Shame on me I wanted it black and not white O:-) maybe that would have helped hours ago before panic ;)

Comment: Is there any possibility to enlarge the generated space to have a default sized graph and some space for labels underneath ?

Comment: @Stefan -- You'll want to play around with `set size` (for example `set size 1,.9`) and also possibly play with the size of the output png -- e.g. `set terminal png size 500,600`.